# cloudfoundry health check fails

Tags: cloud-foundry

The cloudfoundry health check fails.
How do you succeed?
Please let me know if you have the necessary information.

> [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make HTTP request to '/' on port 8080: received status code 404 in 2ms
>
> [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.

Answer (score 0):

The health check is attempting to make an HTTP connection to your application on the assigned port, 8080, and with the default health check path `/`. In your case, it received a 404 response which is not a valid response. You need to return a 200 OK for the test to pass.

If your app doesn't return anything for the endpoint `/`, you can change the path used by the health check by running `cf set-health-check` for your app.

```
$ cf set-health-check -h
NAME:
   set-health-check - Change type of health check performed on an app

USAGE:
   cf set-health-check APP_NAME (process | port | http [--endpoint PATH])

TIP: 'none' has been deprecated but is accepted for 'process'.

EXAMPLES:
   cf set-health-check worker-app process
   cf set-health-check my-web-app http --endpoint /foo

OPTIONS:
   --endpoint      Path on the app (Default: /)
```

Example:

```
cf set-health-check my-cool-app http --endpoint /health
```